# Is it possible to use an Eyefi card to send photos to a server?

Tags: file-transfer, automation, eye-fi

Is it possible to use an Eyefi card to send photos to a server?

Specifically, I want to take photos with a camera that has an Eyefi card in it, and once the photo is taken, I want the photo to be automatically uploaded to a server of my choosing.
Is this possible? Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps you should give more details of the type of server you intend to use as, according to their website, the cards can upload files to (at least) an FTP server - which could form an answer, but would be no help to you if your server can't be accessed via FTP (with the same story for any other protocols that the cards may be able to use).  Do you know the type of server you are likely to target?

Comment: My server does have FTP access. Also, sorry for the vagueness of the question, but I wanted to leave it as opened-ended as possible so that I could possible hear about any and all options. Could you please provide a link to the article/page that talks about how to upload an to FTP server? Thanks.

Comment: A useful clarification might be "to my own server", if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is what they (can) do.
https://x2help.eyefi.com/hc/en-us/articles/200410368-Upload-Photos-and-Videos-to-an-FTP-Server

"An Eyefi Card with Online Sharing enabled can upload photos to a publicly-accessible FTP server instead of a typical online sharing site ("publicly accessible" in this instance is defined as an FTP server that can be accessed over any network, not just the local network). FTP support allows you to send photos (JPEG & RAW) and videos from your Eyefi Card via the Eyefi server to personal and corporate FTP servers that are using passive mode and either the FTP or FTPS protocols. Choosing to upload photos and videos to a corporate or private FTP server is as simple as choosing any other online photo or video destination Eyefi supports."

The card talks to EyeFi central, which then sends it to the server of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

"Yes". That's what they are for. You need to check the eye-fi specs for specific compatibility details.